# View() and messy column names

Tags: r, rstudio

When I do the following in R:

```
x <- c(1,4,3,345,5,4,5,2,34,4,4,5,23,23452,4,3,1,4,34,5,3,43345,
       345,45,345,2345324,23)
View(x)
```

...how can I get rid of a messy column name like below?

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you want?  How about `View(data.frame(a = unname(a)))`

Comment: I can't replicate this in RGui - is this RStudio specific? Using `View(unname(setNames(rnorm(5), rep("sighat",5))))`

Comment: @thelatemail yes. RStudio coerces it to a `data.frame` but does not manage to preserve the name of the original object.

Comment: I don't have Rstudio, but maybe `View(sapply(a, list))` will provide the desired result? It's not really clear what the OP wants to see.

Comment: Answering your re-edit: `View(x = data.frame(x))`

Comment: @RichardScriven Thanks, that works. But is there any way to do it without creating a data frame?

Comment: @ThomasK Thanks. Can you explain further why View() gives a colname like that?

Comment: This is a good question but seems like an issue to take up with the RStudio support team ... this seems like an RStudio bug (for a sufficiently loose definition of "bug" -- Bill Venables might call it an "infelicity")

Comment: @R.Chen See my comment above. Since your object is not a `data.frame` it uses your vector to create the name.

Comment: @ThomasK - `data.frame(x)` works just fine and uses `x` as a column name - `data.frame(c(1,2,3,4))` or similar must be what `View` in the Rstudio world does.

Comment: @thelatemail Yep. Like *Ben Bolker* said, that's probably something for RStudio to fix.

Comment: @BenBolker Got it. Thanks. And thank you thelatemail